# Room and Gson Mapping compatible

Tags: android, persistence, android-room, gson

It is possible to implement a Room mapping on a class that is also implementing parcelable (to map a json object)?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes? Why wouldn't you be able to do that?

Comment: Yes. Add "@Entity" to class and annotate each fields with "@ColumnInfo".